# Google sign in not working well when cookies is disabled.

Tags: ios, google-signin

I've an iOS app that has google sign in feature. The sign in works well when the user has the cookie set to "allow from websites I visit". The sign in doesn't happen when it's set to "Always block". Why is it so?

Comment: What do you mean? It didnt ask for sign in into browser?

Comment: It happens when the user has not signed in into their Gmail account from the browser at least once.

Comment: Please share some code Because I dont have this issue, If My account is not added into safari then it will ask for it

Comment: Tried it again. The problem actually arises when the cookies in the settings is set to "always block". When it's set to "Allow from websites I visit" it works fine as of how expected.